# iOS: UITableView clarification

Tags: objective-c, ios

Does anyone know how to determine if the selected row or selected cell in a UITableView? Can you please help me with this? I am really stuck with this issue for my app.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for. Have you looked at the UITableView documentation? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: yes.. but I just want a code that when this cell is selected, there will be an alert that will occur.. can you help me please?

Comment: Does anyone know how to determine if the selected row or selected cell in a UITableView.... What? Clarify your question. It is literally half of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `indexPathForSelectedRow` or `indexPathsForSelectedRows` to get single or multiple selections.

When a cell is selected, this method of your view controller gets called:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

`indexPath` contains the selected position.

Comment: thanks dasblinkenlight... hmmm.. can i have example for this? thanks so much..

Comment: @AldeeMativo Absolutely! In Xcode, choose "Help/Documentation and API Reference". When the help window opens, type "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" (without double-quotes) into the search window in the upper-left corner. This will bring you many matching documents. At the bottom of the list you will find a dozen of samples, check them out - they demonstrate how this method works.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want your `UITableViewDelegate` to implement [`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a), which will be called whenever a row is tapped.